# LinearLayout imageview doesn't fit on screen?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hi I have a linearlayout and it seems that when I add a second viewflipper that holds two imageviews the second viewflipper is shown on the display screen very tiny.  How do I get the linearlayout to allow me to add more views meaning even if I run out of linearlayout space I can just scroll and the linearlayout will show at the normal size.

For example when you go to a website on your phone you can scroll through the website until you reach the end of the page. I would like the same thing to work for my linearlayout.

Scrollview doesn't work/it only works for one child view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem having one child layout? How about this? ScrollView has just one child and doesn't care home many children its child has.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout> <!-- parent -->
        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> <!-- child 1 -->
        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> <!-- child 2 -->
        <RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout> <!-- child 3 -->
    </LinearLayout>  
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not wrap my LinearLayout within my scrollview which prevented it from working.